# Passing a variable returned by an ajax callback as argument to a PHP method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpexcel

I just want to pass my variable `data.company_name` from callback function:

```
<script>
        function AjaxInsert() {
          var company_name = $("#company_name").val();
          dataToSend = {};
          dataToSend.company_name = company_name;

          $.ajax({
            url: 'insert.php',
            data: dataToSend,
            dataType: "json",
            success : function(data) {
              console.log("my variable: "+data.company_name);
             }
          });//ajax*/
        }
</script>
```

,below in the same script into a PHP (PHPExcel) method:

```
<?php
$var_needed = 'I need that data.company_name here';
$objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0,$num_rows+1,$var_needed);
?>
```

How can be this achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "same script" has been executed already, so you won't be able to interact with it anymore after page load.

You either want to manipulate your spreadsheet client side with a JS library, or to drop ajax and reload the whole page [and ruin your user experience by the way].

Comment: Indeed I guess you are right as the PHP code is executed first with an undefined variable, AJAX comes up to late. I will drop AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$var_needed = $_REQUEST['company_name'];
$objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0,$num_rows+1,$var_needed);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0,$num_rows+1,$_POST['company_name']);
```